# Mapping Ninja Form 'file upload' to custom field type 'file'

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, ninja-forms

I have a Ninja Form that allows users to create a 'draft' post. The post is a custom post type that I created using CPT UI...it's called Resources. I used Advanced Custom Fields plugin to create the corresponding fields that should be receiving data from the Ninja Form submission. All fields are mapping correctly except the uploaded file. The file will get added to Media Library just fine, but don't get pulled into the post that the form submission created. If you use the post admin 'file' custom field to upload a file to the post, it works as you would expect it to. It's just that it won't recognize that i'm trying to send it a file from the Ninja Form. What am I missing?? I feel like this shouldn't require hacking to accomplish and i'm missing something fundamental. Thank you!!!

Comment: Hey, I am also facing the same issue. Have you resolved this issue? Can you put the answer as well(if resolved)?